# How to install "ingress-nginx"?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, windows-10, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress-nginx

I got the following code that uses `ingress-nginx` within `infra\k8s-dev\ingress-srv.yaml` file.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: mysite.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I searched through the internet and found the following command to install it:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

But I am not sure where should I run this command? Is there any `ingress-nginx` package that I also must install from NPM?

I am using Docker-Desktop on Windows 10 machine.

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

Answer (score 2):

Command you have mentioned is right

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.4.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

it self will download and apply the YAML config from URL, it will deploy the Nginx controller. Nginx ingress controller will manage the Ingress you are creating above.

Ingress is rule to divert the traffic and controller manages these rules (ingress).

So just running the apply to K8s cluster context will download and start the PODs of the **Nginx controller**.

as you mentioned in your ingress annotation

```
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
```

that specific ingress rule will get connected or managed by nginx controller.

inside the ingress you have mentioned `mysite.local` so make sure in local setup host file you are mapping the domain to IP.

Once controller is up and running opening the URL (mysite.local) into the browser will show the site.

Comment: Should I run `kubectl apply ...` command in some specific directory?

Comment: In any dir you can run it won’t check for file in dir as it’s downloading from http link

Comment: Should I run this command whenever I want to start the Docker-Desktop?

Comment: It’s one time a setup to install nginx ingress controller